# RequestMapping in Sprint-boot VAADIN application

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Spring-boot VAADIN application with main classes as follows

***Application Class***

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

***VAADIN-UI Class***

```
@Theme("valo")
@SpringUI
public class MyAppUI extends UI {

    @Autowired
    private SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        final VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        setContent(mainLayout);

        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, mainLayout);
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
    }
}
```

***VAADIN-View Class***

```
@SpringView(name = "")
public class MyAppView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        // Some logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        // Some logic here
    }
}
```

Currently, the application handles the request in root URL i.e. say `http://localhost:8080/`. But I want the application to handle requests when a parameter is supplied by `http://localhost:8080/<parameter_value>`. How can I achieve this?

The logic I have to execute is the same in both cases i.e. I want MyAppView to process both root URL request and the one with a parameter value.

Comment: views are opened by their name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VAADIN's `getUI().getPage().getLocation().getPath()` method can be used to get the parameter value from the URL. This will give everything from `'/'` in the URL. Sample code is given below:

***VAADIN-View Class***

```
@SpringView(name = "")
public class MyAppView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        // Some logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
       // Remove spaces and also initial '/' in the path
       String uriParamValue = getUI().getPage().getLocation().getPath().trim().substring(1);
       // Do processing with uriParamValue
    }
}
```